# textfield animation in iPad rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, animation, rotation

I'm starting to upgrading a iPhone App to Universal App, and I have a question: when the user rotates the iPad, how can I animate a couple of textfields?

In portrait, they are at the middle of the view, but in landscape, I want them in the right side of the view.

How can I do that animated?

Thanks,

Rui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the interface is rotating, your view controller's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method will be called. It is called from inside the animation block for the rotation, so changes to any animatable properties should automatically be animated. The implementation should probably look something like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        // Move views to the correct positions for landscape orientation
    } else {
        // Move views to the correct positions for portrait orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: And to animate the textfields, I have only to pass the new position, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to simply assign the `frame` or `center` property of each text field.

Comment: I'm using: usernameTextField.frame = CGRectOffset(usernameTextField.frame, 384, 501);
It desappears from the screen. Any idea why?

Comment: The offset being applied is probably moving it off the screen.